# Using Query Selectors in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, dom

Hi I am working on an angular application and I was wondering if there is anything wrong with using this code in my typescript:

```
let traceLinks = document.querySelectorAll<HTMLElement>('.selected-class');
for (let i = 0; i < traceLinks.length; i++) {
  traceLinks[i].classList.remove('selected-class');
}
let commTypeInputGroup = document.getElementById(selectedId).classList;
commTypeInputGroup.add('selected-class');
```

I have heard that DOM manipulation is bad in angular.  Is it alright for me to do this or should I do something else?

What I need to do is grab any element that has the class selected-class and remove that class then add selected-class to the target id

Comment: If you really need to manually add/remove CSS classes you should consider using [Renderer2](https://angular.io/api/core/Renderer2). That being said, you could probably use `ngClass` in combination with class/component properties, if you broke things down into logical components, to add/remove these respective classes.

Comment: For example, if you links are represented by an interface/class as well as your input groups, they can have a boolean property that represents their "active" status. Then if you break down these elements into tiny "dumb" components, you can conditionally set classes using `ngClass` or `[class.class-name]` based on this object property very easily. It really just depends on how you broke things down. Using built in template API utilities also allows you unit test logic vastly easier as well. There are advantages to using Angular utilities.

Comment: dom manipulation is not only bad in angular, it's bad practice overall. Also, you shouldnt use jquery in an angular app